# Android - GridAdapter issue with Parse Server SDK

Tags: android, gridview, parse-platform

I'm getting into Android and I'm an absolute beginner with that, so I hope you can help me with an issue with my custom GridAdapter and Parse SDK, the Logcat doesn't show me any error but the device still crashes without showing any data.

Here's my code [EDITED]:

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

/* Views */
ProgressDialog progDialog;


/* Variables */
List<ParseObject> eventsArray = null;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    // ProgressDialog
    progDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progDialog.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    progDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    progDialog.show();

    // Call query
    queryEvents();
}



// MARK: - QUERY EVENTS
public  void queryEvents() {

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Configs.EVENTS_CLASS_NAME);
    query.whereEqualTo(Configs.EVENTS_IS_PENDING, false);
    query.orderByAscending(Configs.EVENTS_END_DATE);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException error) {
            if (error == null) {
                eventsArray = objects;
                progDialog.dismiss();


                // CUSTOM GRID ADAPTER
                class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
                    private List<ParseObject> objects;
                    private Context context;


                    public GridAdapter(FindCallback<ParseObject> context, List<ParseObject> objects) {
                        super();
                        this.context = (Context) context;
                        eventsArray = objects;
                    }

                    // CONFIGURE CELL
                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        View gridView;

                        if (convertView == null) {
                            gridView = new View(context);

                            // Get layout from event_cell.xml
                            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_cell, null);

                            // Get title
                            TextView titleTxt = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.titleTxt);
                            if (eventsArray.get(position).getString(Configs.EVENTS_TITLE) != null) {
                                titleTxt.setText(eventsArray.get(position).getString(Configs.EVENTS_TITLE).toString());
                            } else { titleTxt.setText("N/A"); }




                        } else { gridView = (View) convertView; }

                        return gridView;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getCount() {
                        if (eventsArray != null) {
                            return eventsArray.size();
                        }
                        return 0;

                    }

                    @Override
                    public Object getItem(int position) {
                        return eventsArray.get(position);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public long getItemId(int position) {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }


                // Init GridView and set its adapter
                GridView eventsGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.eventsGridView);
                eventsGrid.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(this, eventsArray));

                eventsGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titleTxt)).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });


                // Error in query
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });

}


} //@end
```

I've created an *event_cell.xml*, and I've successfully logged the **eventsArray** in **Home.java** so the Parse SDK works fine, I can gather data from my database (in case you'll think it may be an issue caused by retrieving data from Parse Server).

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should provide your crash logs. I think is null. public EventsGridAdapter(FindCallback<ParseObject> findCallback, List<ParseObject> eventsArray) {
        this.context = context;
        this.events = eventsArray;
    }
 You haven't set context in the constructor.

Comment: thanks so much, and how do I code to get a crash log in the Android Studio console? i only know Log.d()

Comment: Once you crash,  Android logcat show a Error level log. It will show a exception stack trace for you, and a Exception Class and its message.

Comment: Ok, but the problem is that  the Logcat doesn't show anything, it actually says BUILD SUCCESSFUL, and no erro logs :(

Comment: This seems not make sense. In normal case, you will not see build successful in logcat, I think what you see is the gradle console. If you still not see the log, the most usually case is applying a wrong filter, such as Log Level, search string, Regex.

Comment: I know, that's why I can't understand what's wrong in my code, please check this out, it's what I get after running my app: http://s33.postimg.org/yk4576l67/sample.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113643/discussion-between-fvimagination-and-chuntinglin).

Comment: @fvimagination you can follow [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/) it's very clear and helpful.

Comment: ok thanks so much, I'll give it a try

Comment: Regex use no-filter, if it still doesn't work, maybe you should google why crash log not in logcat. or something wrong with your dev env.

Comment: As my first comment, there is a NullPointerException in your code. The constructor argument is without context, so this.context = context still get null. So once you call context.getSystemService, will get a crash by NPE.

Comment: @CarlosJ I've updated the code of my question with FindCallback<ParseObject> context (Android Studio was suggesting me such correction) and a GridAdapter that extends BaseAdapter, the result is the same: app crashes with no messages in Logcat, please check it out, I followed that tutorial but I think it's about that FindCallback<ParseObject> context, If i replace it with Context context, I get this messaghe in the Logcat: Error:(141, 59) error: incompatible types: <anonymous FindCallback<ParseObject>> cannot be converted to Context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set final Context variable in Activity class. Use this variable in the innerClass(FindCallback)

```
public  void queryEvents() {
    final Context myContext= this;
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Configs.EVENTS_CLASS_NAME);
    query.whereEqualTo(Configs.EVENTS_IS_PENDING, false);
    query.orderByAscending(Configs.EVENTS_END_DATE);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException error) {

            ....
            public GridAdapter(Context context, List<ParseObject> objects) {
                super();
                this.context = context;
                eventsArray = objects;
            }
            ...
            eventsGrid.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(myContext, eventsArray));

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You saved my day, thanks so much! If I could upvote your answer 50 times, I would do so :)