# Android ListView adapter not working with Parse SDK

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, parse-platform

I'm an absolute beginner with Android, I can successfully retrieve data from my Parse database but I can't display them into a custom ListView, the wired thing is that the app stops but neither the Android Monitor or Message consoles in Android Studio give me any error, the Message console actually says **Information:BUILD SUCCESSFUL**, the Logcat is totally empty but the app stops with an Alert like **Unfortunately, YourApp has stopped**

Here's my code in the MainActivity.java:

```
 // MARK: - QUERY EVENTS
public  void queryEvents() {

    final ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.test_cell);
    final ListView eventsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.eventsListView);
    eventsListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // Query
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("EventsClass");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException error) {
            if (error == null) {
                eventsArray = objects;
                progDialog.dismiss();

                for (int i = 0; i < eventsArray.size(); i++) {
                    ParseObject eventClass = eventsArray.get(i);
                    String title = eventClass.getString("title");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), eventClass.getString("title"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    listAdapter.add(title);
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Note: If i comment `listAdapter.add(title);` out, the Toast message is fine, it fires all the "title" records from my Parse database, one after the other, and the app doesn't crash. Otherwise, I get no data and the app stops as mentioned above.

My R.layout.*test_cell* is a simple xml file and it's correct, it hosts a LinearLayout with a TextView inside.

What am I doing wrong here? I haven't created any custom ListAdapter.java file, don't know if i really need it with the code above...

Thanks!

Comment: If you are getting a 'Unfortunately, YourApp has stopped' - there really should be something in your logcat from either from the device or emulator you are testing on.

Comment: that's why i said it's wired, I really get nothing in the Logcat :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem in based on how you init `listAdapter`, I'd recommend for you to do two things:

1) Create an `ArrayList<String>` to save all the records that you get from parse

2) To init `listAdapter` make sure to use the constructor that takes as parameters `Context`, `layout`, `id` and `ArrayList`. The first two parameters you already have, just add the third which would be the id of the `TextView` in `R.layout.test_cell` and for the fourth parameter add the `ArrayList` that you create. Make sure to initialise it before this point using `new ArrayList<>()`

3) When you receive your values from parse update the `ArrayList` instead of updating the `Adapter` directly. Something like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < eventsArray.size(); i++) {
                ParseObject eventClass = eventsArray.get(i);
                String title = eventClass.getString("title");
                arrayList.add(title);
    }
    // Once you update your ArrayList you can update the Adapter
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: and what if my test_cell has multiple textViews and an ImageView too?

Comment: Then you will have to use a custom adapter rather than the default `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: ok, any example code for it? I really have no clue about how to make it

Comment: please check this question if you have time: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37585088/3724800

Comment: Android Studio 2.1 has a prepared template for the custom adapter, simplay add a _Fragment with ListView_ to your App. Easier than most of the explanations here on SO